# Is there a german-language online-resource for the prajnaparamita sutra "perfection of wisdom in 8000 lines"?

Tags: reference-request, prajnaparamita

The title says it all: I'm looking for a german translation of that sutra:

Is there a german-language online-resource for the prajnaparamita sutra "perfection of wisdom in 8000 lines"?

(Note, I've the "Heart"- and the "Diamondsuta" which more-or-less belong to the set of Prajnaparamita-sutras, it's just I want to have a look in this specific version of the (possibly earliest) mahayana-sutra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer seems to be, no there isn't. This is somewhat surprising since many Sanskrit Buddhist texts were translated into German.